# Как эффективно отладить java-приложение?

Tags: java, javafx, button

Допустим, у меня есть десктопное приложение. У него есть свои кнопки, нажимая на которые выполняются различные методы. Можно ли посмотреть, не анализируя весь проект, какой именно метод вызвался при нажатии на кнопку? Приложение на javafx

Comment: ctrl+f "название кнопки" для начала?

Comment: Наверное даже ctrl+shift+f, чтобы искало по всему проекту, а не только в классе.А вообще, если проект небольшой, то просто добавить логгирование и повесить на каждый метод.